# how to auto start supervisor installed in a virtual env on host startup/boot

Tags: autostart, virtualenv, supervisord

I have an ubuntu server, and installed supervisor already in side my virtualenv, and it's working when I manually start it up. I also tried to put the init script under /etc/init.d/ folder, but cannot make it work.

Does anyone has an example of the script?Or any suggestion how I can auto start the supervisor?

Here is the template from supervisor github link: https://github.com/Supervisor/initscripts/blob/master/ubuntu

I appreciate the help If anyone can show me what should I change in this script.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky to install supervisor inside the virtualenv. 
I ended up installing on the host, and made it work.

https://www.vultr.com/docs/installing-and-configuring-supervisor-on-ubuntu-16-04

Here is the tutorial I followed.